# Manga where the MC joins a sect which is later destroyed, and subsequently becomes the leader of that sect, vowing to rebuild it

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

So this is what I do remember. It start out as any other cultivation manga out there; he gets accepted into a sect and finds a big sword that he wants to use. One of the people who takes notice of him is an elder, I believe, and that elder begins to help him; this elder also has a brother.

I think about 50 or 60 chapters in, the sect gets destroyed by the leaders of 4 very powerful sects, and the two brothers that are elders, and I believe are also twins, take him to an underground place that is a secret in the sect, and lead him away while they stay and fight.

Since the entire sect was destroyed, he became the sect leader and vows to rebuild that sect. I know this is super vague sorry about not having more information.

Comment: Sounds similar to God of Martial Arts. But I'm not confident enough to post an answer.

Comment: @HyperNym I think I found that one under another title. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Peerless Martial God*](https://peerless-martial-god.fandom.com/wiki/Yun_Hai_Sect) perhaps?

> The Yun Hai Sect is located in the Yun Hai Mountain Range in the Xue Yue. The disciples in the sect are divided as ordinary, elite and core members. The very nature of the sect is incredibly brutal, with students using their family names to tread over each other. Lin Feng ends up rising up to become the number one student just before the sect was destroyed by Duan Tian Lang and is actually made patriarch as the sect falls.
>
> Lin Feng later resurrects the sect with the blood of all those who contributed to its downfall. Though due to the events of the Grave-robbing Empress Xi and the Netherworld Demon Emperor, the Yun Hai Mountain Range is flattened, Lin Feng still expresses his desire to see the resurrection of the Yun Hai Sect. Subsequently, when Lin Feng managed to reach the Tian Qi Layer and returned to Xue Yue, he asked Lin Hai to manage the resurrection of the sect.
>
> When Lin Feng reached the Zun Qi Layer, he returns to the Yun Hai Mountain Range once more, but he finds that it's been rebuilt and that Yun Hai Sect is actually active and thriving once more, with Han Man and Po Jun, acting as patriarchs after being appointed by Lin Hai.

Comment: The OP was talking about the Manhua. I think Peerless Martial God is the title of the light novel. I could be wrong though. I never read the light novel. This is definitely the story I was talking about, but only the light novel version of it. Don't know if it's the one the OP hd in mind. Many Manhua stories have similar elements. I can't imagine that sect destruction is unique with Manhua.

Comment: Thank you all for your input and I know it was very vague however he hit right on the nail's head with that answer. I have gone back and reviewed the Manhua and it is the correct one.