# Manga about a member of a sect, whose leader is from a sect that was destroyed

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

So in the past year, I always get reminded in my head of this manga I used to read. It's martial arts/cultivation-based. I'm not sure of the year, but I think it's from around 2016-2019. This is what I remember:

There is a guy (or a kid?) who's in a sect, and the leader of the sect is actually his guardian from a sect that got destroyed. The kid is the successor, with a seal and maybe a necklace on his body. The kid wandered into a room, where he removed the seal, and the enemies of their family showed up to finish the job. Everyone dies except him and another disciple, who thought he killed everyone, but he was actually controlled by the enemy.

This is what I remember from the start of the manga. I also remember that later on he got locked up by some sects with a demon (I think after he fought a fight on the ring?) which then turns out to be his grandpa which explains to him what happened to their family he heals him and help his cultivation and the grandpa dies.

Hopefully someone can help me with this. !_!

1)Manga was full color

2)the people
responsable for this could be part of the same family + other sects.

3)They referred to them as demons

4)when he meet his grandpa he was chained to the floor and was in a array which mc was thrown into.

5)mc was raised  by the guradian so he had no memories of what happend or what the seal was.

6)manga was mainly humans

7)all of this has happend in the early chapters. (only the part of his grandpa is in the later chapters)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @LogicDictates Thank you!, it was full color.

Comment: I got a bit confused by your description of the plot while editing it. You said that the kid "unlift" (removed?) a seal, and that "enemies of their family showed up to finish the job". Were these enemies responsible for the destruction of the sect the leader was from? And were these enemies human or inhuman? Also, you mentioned that the kid and a disciple were the only two survivors at the end, and that one of them was controlled by the enemy. Which one was controlled though? The kid, or the other disciple?

Comment: @LogicDictates He unseal his powers and the moment he does that they track him down, they was previously a part of the same sect. also I'm pretty sure the other kid saw the mc kill the sect leader a.k.a the guardian while being controlled by that same enemy who came to kill him. Yes they were responsible (later on i recall people call their family demons , but they werent) I hope I recall everything correctly. I think they were humans. The unsealing part was chapter 1/5 the really early ones.

Comment: Did he fight demons/monsters, or just human opponents? And was he unarmed, or did he use a weapon?

Comment: @LogicDictates I'm having a bit of trouble remembering , I'm pretty sure they were humans(or a big OR some part related to dragons) , I do think he uses a big sword later onI'm not entirely sure

Comment: Also he was the son of the leader. not the actuall leader. he later on finds out  by his grandpa that most of the sects were part of this scheme to call them demons and destroy them but I'm pretty sure it was some one related to the family .(He had no memory of it he was raised by the guardian) he fought humans. I know that i dont give much to look at  but thats all I can remember

Comment: Thanks for answering all these questions. It helps to form a clearer picture of what we're looking for. If anyone correctly identifies the manga/manhwa/manhua you're asking about, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: @LogicDictates Thank you for the help.

Comment: Some parts sound similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246412/manga-where-the-mc-joins-a-sect-which-is-later-destroyed-and-subsequently-becom

Comment: @FuzzyBoots unfortunately thats not it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a lot like [Heaven's List](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=148556) by Tian Can Tu Dou, more commonly known by his alias Heavenly Silkworm Potato. The story is set in a shared universe where many of his other stories happened in the past, and the descendants of the main characters from those series make appearances in this one. It is a full color manhua.

[image: Cover art of the manhua]

The MC in this story is Jiang Yinian, who has a seal on his arm that looks like a bandage (not a necklace). The Sect Leader, who is his master/teacher, reinforces this seal regularly using his blood. But the seals have been losing their effectiveness lately.

The eldest senior brother is called Qin Yuan and the second eldest is called Tang Xiu Yan. Second eldest brother doesn't like the eldest and MC is on the eldest brother's side, so doesn't have a good opinion of the second eldest.

The enemies of the sect show up pretty early around Chapter 2 itself, it is just one super powerful guy. This person takes control of the eldest brother and also poisons the sect guardian beast (Nine Abyss Dragon), which starts attacking the sect and killing the disciples.

The Sect Leader seals/locks MC in his quarters where they were cultivating and heads out to see the commotion. He is forced to unseal himself (not the MC) in order to beat the dragon. He notices it was poisoned and is attacked by the enemy, who is a General from the "Demonic Spirit Clan" and calls them traitors. Apparently the MC is a Prince who escaped and the Sect Leader (who was the Grand Elder in the clan) has the royal seal. The Sect Leader lies that the prince is dead. They seem to have fled because someone was taking over the leadership of the clan by force (maybe colluding with other sects, based on the sect leaders vague dialogues).

The enemy makes a show of capturing the eldest disciple, then tosses him over to the Sect Leader. He tries to check if the kid is alright, but gets stabbed by a sword as the enemy is controlling him. He apologizes to his disciple and dies, and **this is witnessed by the second eldest disciple**, who was hiding underwater in a lake. He blames everything on Qin Yuan (not the MC) and flees the sect that's being destroyed, swearing revenge.

MC comes out after this to a destroyed sect, but the enemy is still there and stabs him through the chest. However, he wakes up much later with his wounds healed and that's the start of his journey. His strong grief on seeing his dead teacher seems to somehow unseal his arm, revealing a demonic eye (similar to his teacher), but that doesn't seem to attract anyone. When he pays respects to the dead dragon and swears to get revenge on its behalf, its vertebrae turn into a weapon that he calls "Nine Abyss Mace" and to him it looks like a divine weapon. Even though it's not an actual sword, it does kind of look like a big sword sometimes.

So there were a total of 3 survivors, not 2, but only one of them witnessed the leader's death. The MC learns about his eldest brother's involvement when he runs across the second eldest later on, though he doesn't believe him off the bat.

I wasn't able to find the chapters about his grandpa when I skimmed some later chapters, but this seems like a pretty good match.

Comment: I just checked a few of the early chapters im 90% certain this is it Thank you so much for the help!!